# jquery: animate texts inside spans individually

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a text animation; the idea is some texts will move to left side from right and fade away after five seconds.

I have developed the following code and it is working fine. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHaHK/) But the problem is when I have multiple `spans` with texts, I don't know how to show them individually.

HTML

```
<span class="magic" >Magic1</span>
```

Jquery

```
<script>

var left = $('.magic').offset().left;
$(".magic").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0px"}, 2000);
$(".magic").fadeOut(3000); 

</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.magic {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;

}
</style>
```

I have multiple texts like following, could you please show me how to display/animate them one by one and start the animation from the very beginning when it ends?

```
<span class="magic" >Magic1</span>
<span class="magic" >magic2</span>
<span class="magic" >magic3</span>
// unlimited
```

​
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Every single element in your HTML should have an unique ID. If you want to group them you should use a class attribute (ex. `class="magic"`). However, for this specific question, I recommend using ids with numbers at the end (ex. magic1, magic2, magic3, etc). And having a JS loop to animate each.

Comment: thanks I have changed my code and using a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your markup, but aside from that, you can use recursion and a callback pattern:

UPDATE 2 (with credit to @Madbreaks):: http://jsfiddle.net/JZzdp/6/

```
var magic = $('.magic'),
i = 0,
len = magic.length,
left = $('.container').width(); //SET THIS TO WHATEVER PARENT CONTAINER YOU ARE SLIDING INSIDE

var slide = function(){
  magic.each( function( i ){
    $( this ).delay( i*5000 ).fadeIn().animate({"right":"+="+left},2000, function(){
      $( this ).fadeOut(3000).animate({ "right":"-="+left }, 0, function(){
        if( i === len - 1 ){ slide(); }
      });
    });
  });
}
slide();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. your code is working but its not starting the animation from the very beginning when it ends. And also could you please show me how to keep the text hidden on the right side before its starts moving. Thanks :)

Comment: ah okay so you need it to reset itself? I'll update with that, and how to hide it. :)

Comment: This is painfully complicated IMO

Comment: Agreed @Madbreaks. I'm going to revise it.

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte. After resetting the Slide function for 3 or 4 times all texts inside spans start to move left together. And also it takes a pause after resetting the Slide function after 2 times. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte Thanks a lot It is working perfectly this time :) the code is much easier to understand than before :) thanks a lot for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

First I hope you'd be using class="magic" instead of id="magic" but moving beyond that I would imagine you would just use the "each" iterator like:

$('span.magic').each(function(intIndex) {

$(this).animate({ ... yada yada yada

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8AVgS/)

```
var left = $('.magic:first').offset().left;

$(".magic").each(function(i){
    $(this)
        .css({left:left})
        .delay(i * 5000)
        .animate({"left":"0px"}, 2000, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(3000);
        });
});​
```

Cheers

Comment: Ah, I slightly misunderstood what you were after - updated my answer

Comment: Using the `each()` function could indeed be more efficient. However, regarding the offset, you are assuming all of your nodes are the same width as the first one...

Comment: @JCOC611 They ARE the same width.  Looks at op's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsFiddle, hopefully it is what you wanted. I used the `.delay()` function of jQuery to make the transitions. You can tweak the timing.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/5eNyJ/5/)

```
var mLength = $(".magic").length;

for(var i = 1; i < mLength+1; i++){
    var $magic = $("#magic"+i);
    var offset = $magic.offset().left;
    $magic.css({left:offset}).hide();
    $magic.delay(7000*(i-1));
    $magic.fadeIn(500);
    $magic.animate({"left":"0px"}, 5000); 
    $magic.fadeOut(3000); 
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code is working but the animation does not start from the very beginning when it ends. thanks :)

Comment: No offense (really) but this code is quite inefficient: traversing the DOM to get `$magic` in each loop, calculating `offset` in each loop, etc.  jQuery gives us constructs like `each` that make this quite a bit easier.